# Design pattern for propagation value to base class?

Tags: php, design-patterns, constructor

My class1 inherits from class2 which in turn inherits from class3:

```
Class1

   ^
   |
Class2

   ^ 
   |
Class3
```

now I would like pass a value to constructor of class1, next I pass it to constructor of class2, and in that constructor i passed it to constructor of class3. Is there any design pattern or good practice suited to that problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, if you implement custom constructors for `Class1` and `Class2`, use `parent::__construct($value)`.

```
class Class3 {
    public function __construct($value) {
        // Do stuff with value
    }
}

class Class2 extends Class3 {
    public function __construct($value) {
        parent::__construct($value);

        // Do more stuff with value
    }
}

class Class1 extends Class2 {
    public function __construct($value) {
        parent::__construct($value);

        // Do even more stuff with value
    }
}
```

More on constructors [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php).